# How do you know if a Redirect in an Android App is via Chrome Custom Tab or WebView?

Tags: android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am a new dev in an android app and wanted to know how do I find out if a redirect in an app is to a WebView or a Chrome Custom Tab?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you enabled USB debugging on your Android smartphone  (and granted permission for USB debugging when prompted).

Add the following to your app's code after you instantiate WebView:

```
webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

Then, connect your smartphone to your PC using a USB cable and:

- Open Chrome on your computer and navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices`.
- Wait until your Android smartphone is listed under `Remote Target`, then click the `Inspect` button next to it.
- This will open the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) for your WebView on your smartphone. You can now use the DevTools to debug and inspect the content and behavior of the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Some other easy ways to determine you're in a Custom Tab:

If you have access to the webserver, requests from WebView include "`wv`", for example

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; vivo 1906; wv)
```

Visually in the UI, a Custom Tab says "Running in Chrome" from the top rightmost menu:
[image]